# Print XML with Nokogiri (in Padrino) with good indentation

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, padrino

I want to print out on XML file on HTML Page. 
I'm using Nokogiri with:

```
Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>").to_xml(:indent => 2)
```

but on my HTML page I got:

```
<note>
                    <to>Tove</to>
                    <from>Jani</from>
                    <heading>Reminder</heading>
                    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
                  </note>
```

instead of

```
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
```

I printing it in  with padrino escape function (html_escape).

It seems like that function generate that issue, because in Console everything is correctly printed.

Could you help with me with that issue? I tried to find some answers, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. It was HAML issue, so next time before you want to print out XML or another source code with with html_escape, add

```
= preserve do
  &= escaped_source
```

And everything will properly indent.